# Algorithm to determine minimum of swaps to make two binary arrays identical

Tags: algorithms, binary, sorting

Is there a known algorithm or formula to determine how many swaps are to make a binary array A look like B?

For example if:

```
 Array A =   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 Array B =   [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I took this example from [here](http://www.rhinorisk.com/Publications/Gini%20Coefficients.pdf) , it says that we need 10 swaps to make array B to be ordered like array A. How can we come up with such a number?

Also, it says that:

> to get from the random state to the ideal state would take 6 x 9/2
>   flips (there are 6 bad and 9 goods)

How do we come with such a rule of ((number of zeros)*(number of ones)) / 2 To determine how many swaps it would take to operate from a random state?

EDIT:

What if the array A is more sparse? How do we determine the minimum number of swaps?

```
 Array A =   [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: I can think of an algorithm to do it for an arbitrary array. $O(n^2)$, though you could probably get it to $O(n\log n)$. One would think you could do better for binary arrays but I'm not so sure.

Comment: The algorithm is to sort array B and apply the same permutation to array A, then count the number of pairs of indices $i<j$ in the new array where there is a $1$ at $i$ and a $0$ at $j$. This is assuming we're talking about adjacent swaps.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to bring it down from $O(n^2)$, assuming adjacent swaps. Take $$\text{Array A} = [1, 1, 1, \ldots, 0, 0]$$ and $$\text{Array B} = [0, 0, 0, \ldots, 1, 1]$$, half of them $1$s and half $0$s. You need to at least swap $\frac{n}{2} + (\frac{n}{2} - 1) + \ldots + 1 = O(n^2)$ times

Comment: @demi You don't actually need to do all of the swaps. You could use mergesort to get the permutation. Counting the adjacent swaps can be done by counting the inversions, which can also be done in $O(n\log n)$ time.

Comment: In case the swaps are not adjacent (and mergesort is not about adjacent swaps), just do it in a linear time ( why would you need to do anything more complex ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the "ideal state" is a state of the form

```
[1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0, ..., 0]
```

then we can think of the process of turning an array into the ideal state as moving all the `1`s to the left. If a particular `1` has $k$ `0`s to its left, then we will need to do $k$ swaps where we swap that `1` with a `0` to its left.

In your example

```
Array B =   [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The number of `0`s to the left of each `1` is

```
Zero(B) =   [0, 0, -, 1, -, 2, 2, -, -, -, 5, -, -, -, -]
```

and so the total number of swaps needed to get to the ideal state is $1 + 2 + 2 + 5 = 10$. Any algorithm which doesn't do anything stupid (that is, any algorithm which only performs `0, 1` to `1, 0` swaps) will take this many steps.

In a random state, if there are $a$ `1`s and $b$ `0`s, then each `1` has an expected number of $\frac b2$ `0`s to its right, and so by linearity of expectation, the total number of swaps is $a \cdot \frac b2 = \frac{ab}{2}$, which is the rule you're quoting.

---

If we were instead trying to get from Array B to something like

```
Array C =   [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

then to compute the number of steps we should figure out the same quantity - the number of `0`s to the left - for each `1` in the target Array C:

```
Zero(C) =   [0, -, -, 2, 2, 2, -, -, -, -, 6, -, -, 8, -]
```

Since it never makes sense to swap two adjacent `1`s (that would accomplish nothing), we know that the $i^{\text{th}}$ `1` in Array B should become the $i^{\text{th}}$ `1` in Array C. If we compare these side by side (dropping the `-`s in the expressions above) we get

```
Zero*(B)=   [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 5]
Zero*(C)=   [0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 8]
```

Then we know that, for example, the $5^{\text{th}}$ `1` should change from having $2$ `0`s to its left to having $6$ `0`s to its left, which means it should be swapped with a `0` $4$ times. Therefore the number of swaps necessary is just the sum of the absolute differences between the `Zero*` arrays: in this example,

$$|0-0| + |0-2| + |1-2| + |2-2| + |2-6| + |5-8| = 10.$$

This algorithm has the first algorithm as a special case, since if Array A had all its `1`s before all its `0`s then we'd have

```
Zero*(A)=   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

so the sum of the absolute differences between the `Zero*` arrays is just the sum of the entries of `Zero(B)`: the sum of the number of `0`s to the left of each `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know any ressources about the subject? I didnt find any, I'd like to implement to algorithm which would simply count the number of 0s at the left of each 1s, but I'd like to see if someone else did it to check my program.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. You could check it against small cases which you could also verify by hand?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer I was really busy. Yes it's fine i'll do it myself. But I just realised something. I provided you with a second array which has only 1s on its left, so in this case I understood that you just have to count the number of zeros on the left. What about if the array was more sparsed (I provided an example in the edit)? Thank you

Comment: @user2505650 Well, the example you provided doesn't work because it doesn't have the same number of `1`s as Array B, so no amount of swaps will turn one into the other :) But I've edited my answer to also explain how to handle that case.

Comment: Sorry for the ,mistake, thank you for your excellent explanation!